# Disable automatic Typescript compile in asp core vs 2015

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core

I created a new empty asp core project. I added a simple ts file.

Now per default it is automatically compiled to javascript.

Before asp core there is a option in the projects dialogs. but there are no project dialogs in the current core solution.

I Also tried what is described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176586/how-to-disable-typescript-compilation-in-net-core-projects). 
So I added `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` to the firest property group of the **xproj** file but it doesn't change anything.

Sometime ago I installed the typescript complete package maybe its related to this?

Any advice on how to stop visual studio to autocmpile typescript files in a core application?

xProj now looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>

      <!-- Makes the TypeScript compilation task a no-op -->
      <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">


    <ProjectGuid>43a95da8-804b-459b-8082-fdceb957a8d2</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>GulpTs</RootNamespace>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath Condition="'$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)'=='' ">.\obj</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <OutputPath Condition="'$(OutputPath)'=='' ">.\bin\</OutputPath>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DnxInvisibleContent Include="bower.json" />
    <DnxInvisibleContent Include=".bowerrc" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DotNet.Web\Microsoft.DotNet.Web.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
</Project>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit your tsconfig.json and set `compileOnSave` to `false`.

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

```
{
   "compileOnSave": false,
   "compilerOptions": {
       "noImplicitAny" : true
   }
}
```

Comment: In addition to manual configuration, project types with built-in TypeScript support have a TypeScript Build tab on the project settings page, where the _Compile on save_ option can be toggled.

Comment: but not in in the core project type. what is i asked for ;)

Comment: Toggling the `Compile on save` did nothing for me in the project settings page in VS2017. This solved it!