# Disable MSBuild TypeScript Compile

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, typescript, msbuild

For a Visual Studio projects such as a ASP.NET MVC5, how do you disable compiling of TypeScript files on build/debug?

I currently have `tsconfig.json` `compileOnSave` and `buildOnSave` set to false. Does something need to be added to the projects `.csproj` to ensure it isn't compiled?

When debugging the ASP.NET MVC5 project, it compiles all `.ts` files.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options-in-msbuild.html#typescriptcompileblocked), you can add the property `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` to a PropertyGroup in your csproj file (I added it under the Configuration label). This should disable all msbuild based TS compilation.

With this setting enabled you shouldn't need the tsconfig.json settings compileOnSave/buildOnSave.

If you are on an older version of Visual Studio (I had implicitly thought about VS 2017 or xproj with 2015), the property may be `<TypeScriptEnabled>false</TypeScriptEnabled>`.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I was breaking my head to make it compile on VS2017 final release (released March, 07 2017).

I added `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` as the last node inside the `<PropertyGroup>` and it all worked well. 

FYI, you will still need to compile your TS files externally to VS2017 until they fix this issue.

Comment: Of course, it can also be put in `csproj.user` file. If one does not want to bother team members.

Comment: Why on earth has Microsoft not added a checkbox in the options of Visual Studio, or properties of the project???  Why must we manually edit the proj file???

Comment: I also had to change the build action in the typescript file properties from `Typescript File` to `None` to keep vs2017 from compiling my files.

Comment: This could also be disabled on the msbuild command line by setting the same parameter: "/p:TypeScriptCompileBlocked=True"

Comment: Ok, so if you have added a Folder to your solution via "add existing website" and you don't have a csproj file, how do you get VS 2019 to stop compiling type script in your react app without removing it from the solution?

Answer (score 6):

I had all of this configured, but it still did not fix the issue
(in visual studio 2019).
I added additionally this:

```
 <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>False</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
```

and restarted the visual studio. After that, it started working for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Was enough to reload the project though.

Answer (score 5):

None of the other solutions worked for me and this one caused an error on project load (VS 2019 - 16.9.4)

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>  // doesn't work for me
```

Another way of doing the same thing (albeit with very minor overhead) is to just remove all your TS from the compilation index.

```
<TypeScriptCompile Remove="*" />
```

I use this for avoiding compilation of node modules, like so:

```
<TypeScriptCompile Remove="node_modules\**" />
```

Comment: Adding `<TypeScriptCompile Remove="*" />` to a property group of csproj gives `error  : The attribute "Remove" in element <TypeScriptCompile> is unrecognized.` in VS 16.9.4.

Comment: `TypeScriptCompile` should be used in an `ItemGroup` element.

Answer (score 4):

For Visual Studio 2015, adding below line under PropertyGroup helped me.

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

Answer (score 3):

Next approach worked for me (.NET 6, VS2022, ASP.NET Core + Angular project).
Add this setting to your *.csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue, tested all the things that was posted here without success,

But after adding this, things worked:

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>3.9</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

Seems like the version that I was using did compile no matter the settings.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue related to this which has been open for years.
Still doesn't seem to be a way to turn it off for **website projects**.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/disable-typescriptjavascript-parsing-on-projectsol/354713

The following seemed to work best for me (under Tools > Options > TextEditor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Project > General) to greatly reduce errors in the console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone:

My observation in **VS2022** is, that these and some other properties are **somehow ignored** when Tools -> Environment -> Preview Features -> **Use previews of .NET SDK (requires restart)** is **enabled**