# VS 2015 & msbuild suppress typescript errors

Tags: asp.net, typescript, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

In the solution that I am using, there is one projects that heavily use typescript, I am trying to get this project to pass build in order to run msbuild on it..

Already tried editing `.csproj` file of the project that uses typescript and add to it the property `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>`

under `<PropertyGroup>` element, but this didn't help.
also tried: `<TypeScriptEnabled>false</TypeScriptEnabled>`
and this didn't help either.

How can i set VS2015 to ignore `typescript` 
and also what can i add to 'msbuild' command for it to ignore `typescript` also?

This is the Error List tab after Build:
[image: Error List]

This is Output tab after Build:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable MSBuild TypeScript Compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430300/disable-msbuild-typescript-compile)

Comment: @zgue, i saw that post (all the examples here from that post) but it didnt work for me. do you know why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can i set VS2015 to ignore typescript and also what can i add to 'msbuild' command for it to ignore typescript also?

Not sure the reason why all examples on that post did not work for you, I test the the property `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` on Visual Studio 2015 and it works fine. In order to ensure that you are operating correctly, I would like provide detail info about this method, you can check it.

Add node:

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

Into the first `<PropertyGroup>` in .csproj file, like below:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
  <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
  <ProductVersion>
  </ProductVersion>
  ....
  <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  <TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
  <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
</PropertyGroup>
```

After save this setting, reload your project, re-build the project(with MSBuild project build output verbosity to Detail), you will notice the build log in the output window:

> TypeScript compile is skipped because the TypeScriptCompileBlocked property is set to 'true'.

[image]

Note:The version of `TypeScript tools for Visual Studio` is 1.8.36.0

**Update:**

> then i looked at the "Output" tab but there is no line that contains
>   the text "typescript" the lines there are not related to it

You should change MSBuild project build output verbosity to Detail, then check the log in output window:

[image]

I would like provide another method to suppress typescript errors:

Select the TypeScript file and change it's ContentType to 'Content' instead of 'TypeScriptCompile', then the language service should not give you errors on it.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Test.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**Update for comment**:

If you want suppress TS error when you execute the build from MSBuild command, you can add the property as `/p:TypeScriptCompileBlocked=true`:

Detail info:

1. open a cmd and switch the path to the MSBuild: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`
2. Execute the command: `msbuild "YourProject.csproj" /p:Platform=x64 /p:TypeScriptCompileBlocked=true`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! did exactly what you described here 1) edit the `csproj` file and add to it `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` 2) unload & reload the project 3) build the project > then i looked at the "Output" tab but there is no line that contains the text "typescript" the lines there are not related to it. i will add an image of it in the initial post.

Comment: @E.Meir, I have updated my answer, you can check if it works for you. If not.

Comment: Thanks!  i am getting those messages in the "output" tab `Unknown output: TypeScript compile is skipped because the TypeScriptCompileBlocked property is set to 'true'` also i see messages like this: `1>Target "CompileTypeScript" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(BuildingProject)' != 'false' AND '@(ConfigFiles)' == '' AND '@(TypeScriptCompile)' != '') was evaluated as ('true' != 'false' AND 'tsconfig.json' == '' AND 'src\dashboard\dashboard.spec.ts;' != '').` `TypeScriptCompileBlocked` property override all others?

Comment: @E.Meir, yes, how about the result after set the property <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked> or set build action for .ts files to content?

Comment: In the `.csproj` file i have couple of tags called `TypeScriptCompile`, do you know if i change them to Content if it will effect something?

Comment: also, in VS 2017 i get only this error  ` (TS) Duplicate identifier 'cssPropertySetter`.

Comment: OK, Thanks- now i get "build success" on VS 2017..  just updated the target framework of the project to 4.6.1 from 4.5.2. don't know if it related

Comment: now i need to run `msbuild` command from cmd but i am getting type script errors too, can i add something to the `msbuild` command in order to suppress them? i am runing `msbuild  /p:Platform=x64`

Comment: @E.Meir, I have updated the answer with Update for comment to answer your question in comment, you can check if it help you. If above answer resolve your question, you can mark it as answer, if not, please let me know your question, and if you have more question, I suggest you can open new thread, one thread, one question will be better. Thanks.

Comment: i don't have this path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin` i have `Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0` but it doesn't contain the `msbuild`..

Comment: also- when i run "build", in VS 2017 > in "out" tab it;s writes "succeeded" but in the Error List i see this error: (TS) Duplicate identifier 'cssPropertySetter,, whats up with that? its actual error or no?

Comment: @E.Meir, that path is for MSBuild for Visual Studio 2017 and the MSBuild path for Visual Studio 2015 should be "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin". Besides, if you have an error in the .ts files and compilation is disabled, build will not fail in Visual Studio. But you can still see all errors in Error list tab. And you will still have IntelliSense. This is not actual error.