# Disable Typescript compilation for a website in Visual Studio

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2019

I have an Angular website(not a CS project) added to a solution as shown below:

[image: Angular website in visual studio]

I get a bunch of TS compilation errors generated by Visual Studio 2019, while working on other projects in the same solution, as shown below :

[image]

I could find a solution for disabling TS compilation by Visual Studio when the Angular project files are added to a project here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42430405/1517467  But could not find a solution if it is a website.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? Almost everybody with this issue seems to be using a csproj project so it's really hard to find an answer!

Comment: No @Simon_Weaver, I couldn't figure out an answer. Eventually, my team and I separated the backend API projects and front-end applications into two separate git repo, and for front-end development, we started using VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case some one steel needs it, you can make the node_moduls folder hidden in the file system ,than vs will stop compile the folder

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30706244)