# Tsconfig in angular

Tags: angular

I have this error in `tsconfig.ts`: file:

```
'No inputs were found in config file 'c:/Projects/Angular2//src/tsconfig.json'. 
 Specified 'include' paths were '["src/**/*.ts"]' and 'exclude' paths were '["node_modules"]'.'
```

This is my tsconfig.ts:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "types" : ["node", "jasmine"],
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [ "src/**/*.ts" ],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

Angular 2 v.3 - rc.3, TS. How to implement this? in v.2.0.0 all be normal..

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211566/tsconfig-json-buildno-inputs-were-found-in-config-file). I think you have at least one ts file to compile.

Comment: @Ali Shahzad thanks for quick answer. And now i have this error: `file: ''Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.'`

Answer (score 0):

I am also have the same issue after adding tsconfig.js file in soultion

then i have added on Test.ts file and added below mention line of code in tsconfig file

```
"include": ["**/*"]
,"exclude": ["node_modules","wwwroot" ]
```

then it work for me there is no error at all

I got answer from this [link](https://www.queryoverflow.gdn/query/tsconfig-json-build-no-inputs-were-found-in-config-file-27_41211566.html)