# error TS18003: No inputs were found in config file 'tsconfig.json' when I try to run the React tutorial

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-2019

I'm following the official [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) and when I try to run my app I get the error "error TS18003: No inputs were found in config file 'tsconfig.json'". I also get "the command "npm run build" exited with code 1" but I think that is caused by the first error. If it matters, I'm running the app within Visual Studio 2019 as a node.js app. I'm not sure what I could have possibly done wrong because the tutorial is so simple...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tsconfig.json: Build:No inputs were found in config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211566/tsconfig-json-buildno-inputs-were-found-in-config-file)