# Typescript Compiler emit a single declaration file in s package of a Lerna monorepo

Tags: typescript, lerna

Project structure:

- packages

  - front
  - library

The library tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "include": [
    "**/*.js",
    "additional-types.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/*-test.js",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "AMD",
    "outFile": "global.d.ts",
  }
}
```

The generated file is then imported in the front package via:

```
/// <reference types="@Company/library/global" />
```

The issue is that the declaration paths are not right:

```js
declare module "libraries/utils/generateFrontPath/index" {
  // ...
}
```

Instead of:

```js
declare module "@Company/library/libraries/utils/generateFrontPath" {
  // ...
}
```

The package name (`@Company/library`) is missing  and there is a `/index` at the end that shouldn't be there.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty typescript file to the typescript scripts folder (the location of your tsconfig file) to satisfy the typescript compiler.

That worked for me. I was facing the same issue.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41211721/3997661)

Regards.