# tsconfig.json error in Vuetify project - No inputs were found in config file

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am having a problem with a `tsconfig.json` file in my Vuetify project. The very first `{` has a red squiggle beneath it and on hover shows the following error:

`No inputs were found in config file`

Here is the file.

`tsconfig.json`

```
 { // red squiggle line here
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext",
        "strict": false,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "types": [
          "webpack-env",
          "mocha",
          "chai",
          "vuetify"
        ],
        "paths": {
          "@/*": [
            "src/*"
          ]
        },
        "lib": [
          "esnext",
          "dom",
          "dom.iterable",
          "scripthost"
        ]
      },
      "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.tsx",
        "src/**/*.vue",
        "tests/**/*.ts",
        "tests/**/*.tsx"
      ],
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
      ]
    }
```

I am not really sure what the problem is here. I would appreciate any guidance on how to solve it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see: [tsconfig inputs were not found in config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211566/tsconfig-json-buildno-inputs-were-found-in-config-file)

Comment: @ElvisPimentel thanks for the link. I already have a `main.ts` in my project so unfortunately it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Not sure, you can remove all the paths in "include" and instead add `./src/`.

Answer (score 1):

some possible solutions for this problem.

-First, try restarting VS Code.

-If that doesn’t work, add an empty file.ts file in the same folder where there’s the tsconfig.json file.

-add a ./ before each include path in the config file:

```
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./src/**/*.tsx",
    "./src/**/*.vue",
    "./tests/**/*.ts",
    "./tests/**/*.tsx"
  ]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just curious why adding` ./ `before each included path fixes this tho? are there any explanations?

Comment: it's means "from root"