# setup of vue.js in visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, vuejs2

I tried to setup vue.js in vs2017(framework : asp.netcore mvc). I followed some link which uses WebpackDevMidleware for "Hot module replacement" which is not used in these days.
So, i need a solution to setup vue.js in vs2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to implement a Vuejs based spa along with .net core, asp.net team already providing a bootstrapper here. You can start with this first. 
[VueSpa](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/templates/VueSpa)

Comment: Link broken, it would seem?

Answer (score 1):

You can install vue.js with the Bower package manager

[image: Context Menu]
[image: bower vue package]

Add this scripts to your _Layout.cshtml

```
<script src="~/lib/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
```

If you have a typescript error on build check this [How to disable TypeScript compilation in .Net Core projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176586/how-to-disable-typescript-compilation-in-net-core-projects)

Comment: Thanks for adding the: "How to disable TypeScript compilation!