# Exclude Files of a certain type in Visual Studio Pending Changes

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and becuase I am using Typescript I want to exclude .js and .js.map files from showing in TFS Pending Changes.

Looking at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms245454(v=vs.110).aspx#tfignore it says to add a .tfignore file. So I have tried adding one to the root directory (where the .sln file is). The file contains the following text:

```
*.js
*.js.map
```

I have added this .tfignore file to source control as well and tried restarting Visual Studio, but the .js and .js.map files are still in Pending Changes.

Am I missing anything here, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You're using TFVC?  Are you sure you're using a "local workspace" (not a "server workspace")?  Do those files exist in version control already - did someone accidentally check them in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct answer but I found a work-around for this.

I have webpack compiling and bundling the Typescript files as needed. However it was Visual Studio that was creating individual .js and .js.map files for each typescript file whenever I built the project. Since these weren't strictly needed I added the TypeScriptCompileBlocked element to the .Net Core project file as per [How to disable TypeScript compilation in .Net Core projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176586/how-to-disable-typescript-compilation-in-net-core-projects)

This stopped it from creating the .js and .js.map files on build.