# Disable typescript in visual studio sometime not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, visual-studio, typescript, msbuild

I have merged `Angular 2 CLI` app with `.NET MVC` application. I use `ng commands` to build the application and `VSCode` for `Angular` and `Visual Studio` for `.NET Code`. I want to disable the `Typescript` compilation by `Visual Studio` so that `Visual Studio` should not care about `typescript errors`.

To Disable `typscript compilation by Visual Studio` I have `edited .csproj` project file and added below code [(refer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176586/how-to-disable-typescript-compilation-in-net-core-projects)

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Disables TypeScript compilation  -->
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment line below and add new one

```
 <!--<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />-->
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="False" />
```

Its works fine, but some time start giving `typescript errors in visual studio` as below(screenshot).

[image]

To make errors go away, I do which sometime works:

- `Clean Solution and Build`
- `Restart Visual Studio`

I don't know any better solution for this, any suggestions ?

Comment: it's not ```VSCode errors```  Its ```typescript error in Visual Studio```

Comment: My bad then, I'm removing my comment (but still, post your error as text, not as an image)

Comment: What is the Visual Studio version you are using? Have you update to the latest version of Visual Studio 2017? I can not reproduce this issue with a new blank typescript project.

Comment: I am using ```Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.4.2``` .  I get this ```error``` some times. Is there better way to use ```Angular 2 CLI project with .NET MVC?```